# Does Wiremock mock existing apis

Tags: java, wiremock, stubbing

I have a requirement of mocking an existing api and return what I need to test a web application. Please have the code below. reqres is just an example. I tried to mock it. I need to test an https application. I know the keystore thing. But my code works for no site as of now.

```
public class Some {
public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(8089); // No-args constructor defaults to port 8080
private static WireMockServer wireMockServer;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    wireMockServer = new WireMockServer();
    wireMockServer.start();

    WireMock.configureFor("https://reqres.in/", 8080);
    stubFor(post("/api/users")
            .withHeader("Content-Type", containing("xml"))
            .willReturn(ok()
                    .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .withBody("{\"nice\":\"This was really nice\"}")));
    Thread.sleep(20000);
    wireMockServer.stop();
}
}
```

It gives an exception as such

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: No such host is known (https)
at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:933)
at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1519)
at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:852)
at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1509)
at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1367)
at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1301)
```

Comment: Remove the `https://`. You may also want to read https://wiremock.org/docs/https/

Comment: Also, the title of your question seems to ask an entirely different question than the body of your question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I tried to mock existing api using wiremock.